# Unable to delete an Fdb record entry

Tags: go, foundationdb

Refer to below code: When I try to remove a record that has been saved as tuple.Tuple{"key1", "key2"), The function executes without error but the record is not removed from the database.

```
Foundationdb.Transact(func(tr fdb.Transaction){
            tr.Clear(tuple.Tuple{"key1", "key2"})
        });
```

Is there any thing obvious and particular that I am missing.
Thanks in advance.